# Android- Contact details UI layout

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, android-xml

I'm building a contacts app and wanted to know what the best way of building something like the image below(Jessica is not too shabby...) in terms of using a list view, scrollview, etc.

Ideally, all of my data is in the sql database so a cursor adapter wouldn't be an issue. Is it better to have a listview with separators, or a scrollview where you add views. Since all contacts won't have exactly the same information, what can we do to make that? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have interactive elements inside of the items (e.g. the message button in the screenshot above) I'd recommend a ScrollView. Actually, since you probably don't have that many items I would again recommend a ScrollView. Then it's justa matter of having a set of layouts that you dynamically add depending on the information you have for the contact.